# How to set fields of a struct inside a slice?

Tags: struct, go, slice

I declared a type like this

```
type Klabel struct {
    values []float64
    label  string
}
```

Then, I created a slice of this type like this

```
kdata := []Klabel
```

How can I set the label variable or append a slice of floats to values?

I tried

```
kdata[0].label = "test"
```

and

```
kdata := make([]Klabel, 10)

kdata[0].label = "test"
```

and

```
kdata = append(kdata[0], kdata[0].label = "test")
```

Well, with no success...

So any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You posted this:

```
kdata := make([]Klabel, 10)

kdata[0].label = "test"
```

And it works. When printing the `kdata` slice, output is ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/XcnP4RcOXH)):

```
[{[] test} {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] } {[] }]
```

The output shows `kdata` has 10 elements, and the first has the label value: `"test"`.

To be more clear, print it with:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", kdata)
```

Output:

```
[{values:[] label:test} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:} {values:[] label:}]
```

---

Slices (unlike maps) are addressable. You can change the fields of the elements (that are structs) by simply indexing the slice and assigning new values to the fields.

For example:

```
kdata[0].label = "test"
kdata[0].values = []float64{1.1, 2.2}
kdata[0].values = append(kdata[0].values, 3.3)

fmt.Printf("%+v", kdata[0])
```

Output:

```
{values:[1.1 2.2 3.3] label:test}
```

If you want to append a slice of floats to the `values` field of an element:

```
vals := []float64{1.2, 2.3}

kdata[0].values = append(kdata[0].values, vals...) // Note the 3 dot ...
```

Comment: Well, true, it works. Next time I will read the error messages from the compiler more thoroughly... Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answer, you could also do this:

```
kdata := []Klabel{{label: "test"}}
```

([See on Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/KRacFPUR0a))

But note that the slice length will be 1 rather than 10, so it's not exactly equivalent.